# kotlin retrofit how can i get json from this url?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have an URL and I want to request `Json` with retrofit, but I do not know how to do it
Can anyone help me?

this is my base `url`:

https://api.basalam.com/api/user

```
Request Body (JSON - POST):
{"query": "{productSearch(size: 20) {products {id name
photo(size: LARGE) { url } vendor { name } weight price
rating { rating count: signals } } } }"
```

Comment: Here's a tutorial:  https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Comment: can you more explain please? 
how should i use parameters to get request?

Comment: do you want to receive or send data?, what is you question exactly?

Comment: i want to receive data from base url with parameters

Comment: look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/basic-usage-of-retrofit-in-kotlin-for-fetching-json-8b9d37999058) and for more info:

First you need the model (data class)

```
data class CustomizeWrapper(
    @SerializedName("success")
    var success: Boolean,
    @SerializedName("message")
    var message: String,
    @SerializedName("data")
    var data: Int
)
```

Second thing you need the End pint interface which will contain all of your endpoints

```
interface EndpointInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("add_customize")
    fun addCustomize(
        @Field("customize_id") customize_id: Int,
        @Field("item_id") item_id: Int,
        @Field("price") price: Float,
        @Field("quantity") quantity: Int,
        @Field("company") company: String
    ): Call<CustomizeWrapper>

}
```

Last thing you need to call the API

```
private fun addCustomize(customizeId: Int, item_id: Int, price: Float) {

    val call: Call<CustomizeWrapper> =  App.instance.api.getData.addCustomize(customizeId, item_id, price, 1, App.instance.cacheManager.getCompanyName() )
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<CustomizeWrapper> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<CustomizeWrapper>?, response: retrofit2.Response<CustomizeWrapper>?) {
            AppLogger.log("test", response.toString())
            AppLogger.log("test", response!!.body().toString())

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<CustomizeWrapper>?,  t: Throwable?) {
            AppLogger.log("test", "Failed to add order : $t")

        }
    })
}
```

But don't forget to check if you API is (POST, GET, ....)

You must define that in the function in the EndpointInterface